# How to use scoverage with Flink shadowjar custom gradle dependency configuration

Tags: build.gradle, apache-flink, scoverage

## Summary

I've got a Gradle Flink Scala project and am trying to add Scoverage reports, but the `compileScoverageScala` task can't find all the dependencies due to the custom shadow jar configuration.

## build.gradle

Here's the build file, which follows Flink's Gradle example.  The only difference is I've tried to add Scoverage.

```
// Here are the plugins I'm using
plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id 'application'
    // shadow plugin to produce fat JARs
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
    id "org.scoverage" version "4.0.1"
    id "com.github.maiflai.scalatest" version "0.25"
}
...

// Here's the custom configuration used to build the shadow jar without including the main Flink libraries
configurations {
    flinkShadowJar // dependencies which go into the shadowJar

    // always exclude these (also from transitive dependencies) since they are provided by Flink
    flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'org.apache.flink', module: 'force-shading'
    flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', module: 'jsr305'
    flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
    flinkShadowJar.exclude group: 'log4j'
}
...

// Here's where the custom configuration is added to the classpath, Scoverage isn't picking these up.
sourceSets {
    main.compileClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
    main.runtimeClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar

    test.compileClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
    test.runtimeClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar

    javadoc.classpath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
}
```

Here's the build output:

```
$ ./gradlew clean build

> Task :compileScala
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.

> Task :compileScoverageScala FAILED
Pruning sources from previous analysis, due to incompatible CompileSetup.
/Users/david.perkins/dev/wffh/flink-validation-fhir/src/main/scala/com/ibm/watson/health/foundation/hri/flink/FhirValidationJob.scala:6: object core is not a member of package com.ibm.watson.health.foundation.hri.flink
import com.ibm.watson.health.foundation.hri.flink.core.BaseValidationJob
                                                  ^
```

The missing package is declared as a `flinkShadowJar` dependency. The `compileScala` task is able to find it, but `compileScoverageScala` can't.

Anyone know if there's a way to explicitly tell Scoverage to include the `flinkShadowJar` configuration?  I'm hoping others using Flink have run into this before and know a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got some help from the Scoverage team: https://github.com/scoverage/gradle-scoverage/issues/138

Adding this to my sourceSets declaration fixed it.

```
    scoverage.compileClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
    scoverage.runtimeClasspath += configurations.flinkShadowJar
```